# Azure ARM Deployment - multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure, templates, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

My ARM template has worked well, it creates a VNET, multiple subnets, NSGs, and necessary route-tables. I now need to do this same thing but across multiple subscriptions. Can't get it to work.

I know there is the nestedTemplate option. This allows you to specify a subscriptionID and requires that the resource group exist first. I built all this up and used the nestedTemplate but get an error "Subscription is not registered with NRP". Not sure how to make this work and I'm wondering if an ARM template is enough. I'm thinking of building a python script that will in turn run arm templates with separate parameter files.

I'd like to be able to take this single template and single parameter file but have it iterate through multiple subscriptions.

Comment: No idea what that is. Logged out and logged back in via az-cli and it is gone.. but I'm getting template errors now. I'm thinking it is because of the nestedTemplates.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't get it to work, the nestedTemplates seem to require additional work. I built a python script that does the work instead.

Comment: @ Nathan. I am trying to implement the same solution cna you please share your python script here ?